# What is the size of the biggest subset such that none of its element is bigger k times than the other?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Consider sequence $1, 2, 3, ..., N$. What is the size of the biggest subset such that none of its elements is bigger $K$ times than the other? For example if $N = 9$ and $K = 3$ then answer is $7$ because you can take for example everything except $3$ and $6$

Comment: In the set $\{1,2,4,5,7,8,9\}$, we have that $9$ is $9$ times bigger than $1$, which is more than $3$ times $1$. I don't get your question.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: It is nevertheless not bigger **exactly** $3$ times as $1$. I do agree, however, that the term "bigger" implies "at least", and that the question should probably be rephrased.

Comment: K is specified. In this example k is 3 so 3 and 6 cant be in the set simultaneously. Also 3 and 9 cant be

Comment: @barakmanos Oh it's exactly. I understood now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An optimal strategy is clearly to exclude all numbers of the form $aK^{2n+1}$ with $K\nmid a$. The amount of such numbers in $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ is $\lfloor \frac NK\rfloor - \lfloor \frac N{K^2}\rfloor + \lfloor \frac N{K^3}\rfloor -\dots$ Thus, the answer to your question is
$$
M_N = \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \log_K N\rfloor}(-1)^n \left\lfloor \frac N{K^n}\right \rfloor. 
$$

---

There seem to be no shorter form of $M_N$, but some alternative description. Namely, write $N$ in the $K$-nary system, i.e. $N = \sum_{j=0}^m a_j K^j$ with $a_j\in \{0,1,\dots,K-1\}$. Then 
$$
M_N = \frac1{K+1} (KN+T_K(N)),
$$
where $T_K(N) = \sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j a_j$ is the "alternating sum of digits" of $N$. E.g. for $N=100 = \overline{10201}_3$ and $K=3$, $T_K(N) = 1-0+2-0+1 = 4$, so $M_N = \frac14(300+4) = 76$.

Comment: I suspect you could use something other than $k$ for your summation index, and then replace $3$ by the more general $k$ of the question